# Unable to traverse vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Hey I am trying to sort given input into a wave array.

Given an array of integers, sort the array into a wave like array and return it,
In other words, arrange the elements into a sequence such that a1 >= a2 <= a3 >= a4 <= a5.....

Given [1, 2, 3, 4]

One possible answer : [2, 1, 4, 3]

Another possible answer : [4, 1, 3, 2]

```
vector<int> Solution::wave(vector<int> &A) {
    int size = A.size();
    for (int i=0; i < size ; i++)
    {
        int min =0;
       sort(A.begin(),A.end());
        for (auto it = A.begin(); it != A.end(); it++) {
        if(A[it+1]>A[it])
        {
            int temp=0;
            temp = A[it+1];
            A[it+1]=A[it];
            A[it]=temp;
        }

       }
    }
    }
}
```

Error :-

```
solution.cpp: In member function 'std::vector<int> Solution::wave(std::vector<int>&)':
solution.cpp:8:13: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::vector<int>' and '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >')
         if(A[it+1]>A[it])
             ^
solution.cpp:8:13: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:64:0,
                 from solution.h:13,
                 from solution.cpp:-3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:770:7: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[](std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = int&; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]
       operator[](size_type __n)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:770:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >' to 'std::vector<int>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:785:7: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[](std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) const [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_reference = const int&; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]
       operator[](size_type __n) const
   ^
```

Source :- https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/wave-array/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing elements of a vector you either use iterators:

```
for( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it )
    std::cout << *it;
```

or index:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i )
    std::cout << v[i];
```

choose one, do not mix them.

Note: there is [`std::swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) function, you do not need to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

A.begin() returns an iterator pointing to the begin of the vector, so you can access to the element using *A.begin().

So A[it+1] makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 1):

An iterator in C++ is a wrapper for some sort of reference to a location in a container. `it` is not an integer, but in this case , `vector<int>`, `it` refers to an integer.

So `it` cannot be used as a subscript index, but `*it` can.

In

```
if(A[it+1]>A[it])
```

`it+1` does not resolve to the number at `it` plus 1, it resolves to an iterator to the vector element after `it`. Likely you mean to write

```
if(A[*(it+1)]>A[*it])
```

Breaking that down,

1. `it+1`: reference element after `it`. Lets call this element 1
2. `*(it+1)`: get value at element after `it`. Following through from
   above, this is the same as `A[1]` and let's say the value at `A[1]`
   is 42.
3. `A[*(it+1)]`: is `A[A[1]]` or `A[42]`

This will compile, but it won't do what it seems you are trying to do.

Instead you likely want to directly compare the integers.

```
if(*(it+1)>*it)
```

and similar for all subsequent variants of `A[it]` in the code.

This will allow you to debug the other problems in your algorithm, something I'm not going to address because this looks like an assignment or challenge of some sort.

Except for this:

```
for (auto it = A.begin(); it != A.end(); it++)
```

allows `it` to range from the beginning of the `vector` to the end and needs extra guards so that `*(it+1)` cannot reach past the end of the `vector` when you reach the end of the `vector`. You can

```
for (auto it = A.begin(); it != A.end() - 1; it++)
```

but if you poke around you might find a better option.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your loop.

it is an iterator.  To get the value of it is *it and the contents of it+1 is *(it+1).

Your loop should only go to size-1, otherwise you'll be comparing the last value to an invalid value.

std::swap() will be more efficient than a hand coded swap as it will use moves rather than copies.

You probably meant to increment the the loop by 2 so it+=2 in your for loop.

You should check for an odd length and take appropriate action.

Mike